# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the equation $f(x)=(1+\cos x)/2$ for $-\pi\leq x\leq \pi$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image: q]

I already proved that $f$ is of class $C^1$, but I have many doubts with this example:

1. Why the collection $\{\phi_i\}$ forms a partition of unity on $\mathbb{R}$? I know that $\phi_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,2,3,...$, plus $S_i$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, but Why $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i=1$?
   P?

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}f(x-m\pi)+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f(x+m\pi)$ but what else can I do? Thank you very much.

**Edit:** We know that $\phi_{2m}(x)=0$ for $|x+m\pi|>\pi$ and $\phi_{2m+1}(x)=0$ for $|x-m\pi|>\pi$ by definition, that is $\phi_{2m}(x)=0$ for $x\notin [-(m+1)\pi,(-m+1)\pi]$ and $\phi_{2m+1}(x)=0$ for $x\notin [(m-1)\pi, (m+1)\pi]$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then there is a $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\in [-(m+1)\pi,(-m+1)\pi]$ or $x\in [(m-1)\pi, (m+1)\pi]$, in the first case

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)=\phi_{2m}(x)+\phi_{2m+2}=1$ or

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)=\phi_{2m}(x)+\phi_{2m-2}=1$

In the same way the other case is made, is this reasoning correct?

Comment: There's no infinite sum here.  At any point only finitely many of the functions are nonzero.  What is the support of $\phi_n$?

Comment: Only need check $\phi_1+\phi_3=1$ on $[0,\pi]$ and use symmetry.

Comment: @saulspatz  What is the support of $ϕ_n$?

Comment: Note, for example, that $\phi_2m(x)=0\text{ for }|x+m\pi|>\pi$ so the support is $[-(m+1)\pi, (-m+1)\pi]$

Comment: @saulspatz 
See my edition please and give me some suggestions.

Comment: @saulspatz Why $f$ is of class $C^1$?

Comment: The sum of finitely many continuous functions is continuous.